# How do I prove this modulo relation?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

*Any suggestions for a better title would be greatly appreciated.*

This is related to a [Codeforces problem](https://codeforces.com/contest/1359/problem/E) for modulo arithmetic.

Given an array of non-negative positive integers:

$[a_1, a_2, \dots,       a_k]$

If $ a_2, \dots, a_k$ are all some multiples of $a_1$, I have to prove that for every non-negative integer $x$ in the array:

$(((x \bmod a_1) \bmod a_2) \dots \bmod a_{k - 1}) \bmod       a_k = (((x \bmod a_{p_1}) \bmod a_{p_2}) \dots \bmod a_{p_{k -       1}}) \bmod a_{p_k}$

where $a_p$ refers to every permutation of the array.

Example:

```
n=3 Array: [3, 12, 24]
Result = 0
n=3 Array: [3, 24, 12]
Result = 0
n=3 Array: [12, 3, 24]
Result = 0
n=3 Array: [12, 24, 3]
Result = 0
n=3 Array: [24, 12, 3]
Result = 0
n=3 Array: [24, 3, 12]
Result = 0
n=12 Array: [3, 12, 24]
Result = 0
n=12 Array: [3, 24, 12]
Result = 0
n=12 Array: [12, 3, 24]
Result = 0
n=12 Array: [12, 24, 3]
Result = 0
n=12 Array: [24, 12, 3]
Result = 0
n=12 Array: [24, 3, 12]
Result = 0
n=24 Array: [3, 12, 24]
Result = 0
n=24 Array: [3, 24, 12]
Result = 0
n=24 Array: [12, 3, 24]
Result = 0
n=24 Array: [12, 24, 3]
Result = 0
n=24 Array: [24, 12, 3]
Result = 0
n=24 Array: [24, 3, 12]
Result = 0
```

**What I have tried:**

I know that a `multiple of one number` mod `another multiple of the same number` will yield either 0 or another multiple. **But I simply cannot understand why this can't be the case for non-multiples as well ?**

Comment: "But I simply cannot understand why this can't be the case for non-multiples as well ?"  Suppose $a$ and $n$ are not both multiples of the same number.  Then they are relatively prime.  Since there are reltatively prime there exist $k,j$ so that $ak +nj=1$ and $ak \equiv 1 \pmod n$ and $1$ is not a multiple of anything.

Comment: @fleablood You have to excuse my ignorance, but what do you mean by $k$ and $j$ ? Is this a particular number theory property that you are referring to ?

Comment: Bezouts lemma.  If $a,n$ are relatively prime there will exist/we will be able to find two integers which we will call $k$ and $j$ so that $ak + nj = 1$  (obviously one of the integers will be negative and the other possitive.  So if $ak + nj = 1$ then $ak = 1 - nj$ and so $ak \equiv 1 \pmod n$.

Comment: Bezouts lemma can be express as if $\gcd(a,n) =d$ then for any integer $v,w$ then $av + nw = $ some multiple of $d$.  And there will exist integers $k,j$ so that $ak + nj = d$.  And for any mulitple of $d$, say $dh$ then $a(kh) + n(jh) = dh$ so solutions will exist for all multiple of $d$.  So that is why your result holds: If $\gcd(a,n) = d$ not only will all $ak$ but congruent to a multiple of $d$. For any multiple $dm$ there will be a $k$ where $ak \equiv dm \pmod n$.

Comment: WHat does: "$(((x \bmod a_1) \bmod a_2) \dots \bmod a_{k - 1}) \bmod       a_k = (((x \bmod a_{p_1}) \bmod a_{p_2}) \dots \bmod a_{p_{k -       1}}) \bmod a_{p_k}$" mean?  What does $b \bmod n = c\bmod m$ mean?

Comment: "But I simply cannot understand why this can't be the case for non-multiples as well ?"  Why do you care?  That's not part of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

After mod $a_1$, the result is already smaller than all of the elements in the array, so taking further modulos is unnecessary. All we have left to prove is that taking mod $ka$ for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ will not change the remainder of division by $a$.
Can you prove that?

Comment: How can you say that 'After $mod a_1$, the result is already smaller than all of the elements in the array' ? Imagine an array `[3,15,24]` `24 mod 15 = 9` which is not smaller than all the elements in the array. Could you please elaborate by what you mean ?

Comment: $24 \mod 15 = 9$ and then $9\mod 3 = 0$.  If you are modding by all $a_i$ you will eventually eventually mod by $a_1$ and as all the results are multiples of $a_1$ then when you mod by $a_1$ you will get $0$.

Comment: $15$ is $a_2$.  Not $a_1$.  YOu haven't modded by $a_1$ yet.  So *AFTER* you mod by $a_1$ you will have a number less than $a_1$ and thus less than all elements in the area.  In fact, as all the elements are multiples of $a_1$ you will get $0$ always.